# Transforming a 3d object from cartesian and plot it on Geographic Projection

Tags: python, math, geolocation, plotly-python, geo

I am trying to plot a 3d balloon on 3d geographic plane at a specific lat (deg), lon (deg), and alt (m), using Plotly. The balloon is generated using the `get_balloon` function in Cartesian coordinates.
I'm currently struggling to convert these Cartesian coordinates to geographic coordinates, but it gets deformed.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def get_balloon(radius):
    upper_radius = 0.8 * radius
    lower_radius = 0.05 * radius
    mid_height = 0.6 * radius
    major_axis = 1.5 * radius

    # Create the theta and phi values for the spherical coordinate system
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200)
    phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

    # Create a meshgrid from theta and phi
    theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)

    # Convert the spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates
    upper_x = upper_radius * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    upper_y = upper_radius * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    upper_z = major_axis + mid_height + upper_radius * np.cos(phi)

    lower_x = lower_radius * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    lower_y = lower_radius * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    lower_z = major_axis - mid_height + (major_axis/4) * np.cos(phi)

    # Combine the coordinates for the upper and lower parts of the balloon
    x = np.concatenate((upper_x, lower_x))
    y = np.concatenate((upper_y, lower_y))
    z = np.concatenate((upper_z, lower_z))

    return x,y,z


def plot_balloon(radius):
    x,y,z = get_balloon(radius)
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale='Reds', showscale=False))
    fig.show()

# Call the function with the radius of the balloon
plot_balloon(radius=1)
```

[image: Cartesian]

This is how I transform it (unsure if it's correct)

```
def plot_balloon_at_geolocation(lat, lon, altitude, radius):
    # Earth's effective radius (in meters)
    earth_radius = 6371e3  # average radius

    # Generate balloon
    x, y, z = get_balloon(radius)

    # Adjust the x, y, z coordinates of the balloon to place it at the desired geolocation
    x = x / earth_radius + lon  # divide by earth_radius to convert to degrees
    y = y / earth_radius + lat  # divide by earth_radius to convert to degrees
    z = z + altitude  # altitude is already in meters
    
    # Plot the balloon
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale='Reds', showscale=False))
    fig.update_layout(title="3D Balloon at Latitude {}, Longitude {}".format(lat, lon))
    fig.show()

# Call the function
plot_balloon_at_geolocation(lat=32, lon=-88, altitude=60, radius=100)
```

[image: geo_coords]